# Как задать фиксированный размер элемента?

Tags: html, css

Всем привет, хочу сделать фиксированный размер для тега

`<fieldset> </fieldset>`

Но беда в том, что когда я вытаскиваю из базы длинный текст, то вместо того, чтобы перевести текст на новую строку, расширяется сам элемент и залазит на другие. Пример видно на скрине ниже:

[image]

Answer (score 3):

Попробуйте силу кроссбраузерного css, но в строчке должен быть хоть один пробел, такх длинных слов не бывает)

```
div {

    white-space: pre;         /* CSS2 */
    white-space: pre-wrap; /* CSS 2.1 */
    white-space: pre-line;   /* CSS 2.1/3 */
    white-space: -moz-pre-wrap !important; /* Mozilla */
    white-space: -hp-pre-wrap;   /* HP printers */
    white-space: -o-pre-wrap;     /* Opera 7 */
    white-space: -pre-wrap;       /* Opera 4-6 */
    word-wrap: break-word;       /* Internet Explorer 5.5+ */
}
```